# Contact form 7 wordpress multi step variable

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I have a similar problem with my form. I have the code:

on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http:///page/subpage/');"

and on this page http:///page/subpage I won't print message:

Dear: Peter <-'Peter' is  variable form previous form.

I create multi step form.

Comment: You are only redirecting the page like this AFTER the mail is sent ..

Comment: You also might want to check the [multistep plugin for wpcf7](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/)

Comment: My form works fine, but how to transfer and post variable to next step form